# Is there a similar way to insert new column with values into excel in openpyxl?

Tags: openpyxl

```
workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_name)
sheet = workbook.worksheets[0]

column_list = [cell.value for cell in sheet[1]]
column_dict = {column:idx for idx, column in enumerate(column_list)}

row_count = sheet.max_row
new_column = [False] * row_count
...
new_column = [False, False, True, True, False, ...]
```

I want to insert the 'new_column' into the sheet. How to do that? I know I can insert new column by index, but this only inserting empty column and how to add column name and cell values?

```
sheet.insert_cols(2)
```

In Pandas, it's done:

```
df['new_column'] = new_column
```

Can this be done similarily in openpyxl?

Comment: Excel is a row-oriented file format. Because we support streaming, you **must** be prepared to provide data row by row. But it's easy enough to write a function to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following

```
    ######
    import openpyxl
    
    
    class CustomOpenpyxl:
    
        def __init__(self, _my_file_name):
            assert _my_file_name.split('.')[-1] == 'xlsx', 'Input file is not xlsx'
            self.my_file_name = _my_file_name
            self.my_base_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.my_file_name, read_only=False)
            # following line will set the last worksheet in the workbook as active
            self.my_base_active_ws = self.my_base_wb.active
            # following line will get the maximum row number in active worksheet
            self.my_base_active_ws_max_row = self.my_base_wb.active.max_row
            # following line will get the maximum column number in active worksheet
            self.my_base_active_ws_max_col = self.my_base_active_ws.max_column
            # following line will get the column names (as list) in active worksheet
            self.my_base_active_ws_col_titles = [_col_name[0].value for _col_name in self.my_base_active_ws.iter_cols()]
    
        # Method to get column titles for active worksheet
        # Argument to this method is: - Row number of Header Values
        def get_col_names_active_ws(self, _header_row_num):
            self.my_base_active_ws_col_titles = [_col_name.value for _col_name in
                                                 self.my_base_active_ws[_header_row_num]]
            return self.my_base_active_ws_col_titles
    
        # Method to add a new column with name as the last column of worksheet
        # Arguments to this method are: - New column name and row number of headers
        def add_new_col_at_the_end_to_active_ws(self, _new_col_name, _header_row_num):
            # New column will be added only if, it does not exist already
            if _new_col_name not in self.get_col_names_active_ws(_header_row_num):
                # Note:- Since we are adding the column at the end, we need to auto identify its index
                # We are using the existing max_column property of the worksheet and incrementing it by 1
                _new_col_idx = self.my_base_active_ws_max_col + 1
                # Once the columns is added, we correctly identify the cell where the column name will be written
                self.my_base_active_ws.cell(row=_header_row_num, column=_new_col_idx).value = _new_col_name
                # This method calls save internally, hence its auto save from user perspective
                self.save_wb()
    
        # Method to save the workbook
        # No arguments to this method
        def save_wb(self):
            return self.my_base_wb.save(self.my_filename)
    
        # Method to add multiple columns with names as the last column of active worksheet
        # Arguments to this method are:- Column Names (as an iterable), and row number of header row
        def add_multiple_cols_at_the_end_to_active_ws(self, _col_names, _header_row_num):
            # Iterate over the values in the iterable (column name)
            for _ in _col_names:
                # call the function 'add_new_col_at_the_end_to_active_ws' and pass the column name
                self.add_new_col_at_the_end_to_active_ws(_, _header_row_num)
                # Most important step is to reload the workbook, so that changes from last iteration are reloaded
                self.reload_wb()
    
        # Method to reload the workbook after any value update or column additions
        # No argument to this method
        def reload_wb(self):
            # Call the initialization method with the file name to reload
            # since "openpyxl.load_workbook(self.my_filename, read_only=False)" is part of initialization
            self.__init__(self.my_filename)
    
    ######
```

Comment: Import this class or simply the method - "add_new_column_specific_idx_to_active_ws"
Make changes accordingly, and it should help you add the column and provide a name for it.

Comment: Thanks, @Ashi Samarth. I chose to use pandas to load the csv file and the thing is much simpler now. Thanks for the suggestion. Just wondering since pandas already provided csv functionality, why does openpyxl exist?

Comment: I'll share my experience:
If you are dealing with a workbook with a single worksheet then Pandas is faster and better choice. However if you are working with multi-sheet workbook where cell formatting is also required, then openpyxl is a better and faster option.